# How to disable NGINX static media url root

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I used nginx static url to call media file, like bellow:

```
server {

# other configs

location /media/profile_pics/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/myuser/mymedia/profile_pics/;
}

# other configs

}
```

It works fine, I can get my image with this url : https://mydomain/media/profile_pics/image.jpg

But, the problem was when I'm accessing https://mydomain/media/profile_pics/ the browser show all images in the media directory. So, how to raise 403 when user accessing this url?

Thanks :)

Comment: What you are describing is the behaviour of `autoindex on;`. Try setting `autoindex off;`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith thankyou it works for me :)